# How does WordPress recognize my mobile theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, themes

I already know HTML, CSS and PHP but I'm a complete beginner in WordPress. I've already set up my WordPress-Theme for Desktop and I'm happy with it and now I've tried to make some tweaks for the mobile theme, but when I open my page on my mobile phone, those changes don't show up. They do show up, in fact, when I scale down my browser window - but not on mobile.

I've tried to make the mobile theme by overwriting the CSS-Selectors with the following:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    …
}
```

Could it be that WordPress doesn't recognice the @media-Selector? Is there any other CSS-only way to do this without using any plug-ins?

I've already tried finding an answer to my question but all I can find is about plug-ins.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All modern browsers recognise media queries, using Wordpress would not change that. Do you have this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in your head section? This forces mobile devices to not attempt to make it's own changes, such as zooming out and changing the font sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be a WordPress issue, as CSS is interpreted only by the client (being the mobile device or your pc). This may be fixed by adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

to your `<head>`?